# How to ReRun tests that errored out in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-surefire-plugin

I have tried Flaky Test Handler Plugin(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flaky+Test+Handler+Plugin) by using -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 in jenkins, but this is only rerunning **failed** jobs.

I wanted to re-run tests that errored out, not the entire jenkins job but only the errored out jobs in a job

Below is the output in jenkins when using 'Flaky Test Handler Plugin', is there any way to tweak this plugin and make it to re-run errored tests also

Results :

Tests in error: 
test1 » InvokerInvocation

Failures:

Run 1: test2:86 » MissingMethod

Run 2: test2:86 » MissingMethod

Run 3: test2:86 » MissingMethod

Comment: What are you using to run your tests? The best solution would be to build retry logic into your test runner (ex, https://github.com/NoRedInk/rspec-retry for rspec) instead of trying to re-run the whole jenkins job.

Comment: These are groovy tests(geb selenium) running in jenkins using maven